# Apache FOP 2.2 -> 2.3, paginating

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I've come across a problem when migrating/upgrading FOP from version 2.2 to 2.3. Paginator stopped working... Here is sample code:

Main "template":

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.1" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
<fo:page-sequence 
    master-reference="templates/A4.xsl" 
    initial-page-number="1" 
    font-size="9pt" 
    font-weight="plain"
    font-family="Arial"
>

    <section id="footer" filename="templates/ftr_PgNmb.xsl" />

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

        <fo:block >Page 1</fo:block>

        <fo:block page-break-before="always"/>
        <fo:block >Page 2</fo:block>

        <fo:block page-break-before="always"/>
        <fo:block>Page 3</fo:block>

        <fo:block id="last-page" />

    </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>
```

Paginator 1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
exclude-result-prefixes="fo"
>
<xsl:apply-templates select="templates/ftr_PgNmbTemplate.xsl"/>
```

Paginator 2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
<xsl:template match="templates/ftr_PgNmbTemplate.xsl">  
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after-firstpage">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
            <fo:table-column />
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                            Page <fo:page-number /> of <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>

<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after-otherpages">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                            Page <fo:page-number /> of <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>

</xsl:template>
```

Error that I get is:

> SEVERE: Error while serializing page 1. Reason: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)

Any hints? I've got no clue whatsoever. All I've discovered is that the problem is with `<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page"/>` call. If that is removed PDF is created just fine. With it... nope.

EDIT: Complete xsl for generation:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [FOP's help page about FO](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-total-pages):

> ...
>   To accomplish this in **XSL 1.0**, place an empty block with an id at the end of the flow:

```
<fo:flow ...>
  ...
  <!-- block, NOT page-sequence -->
  <fo:block id="last-page"/>
</fo:flow>
```

Get the number of the last page as follows:

```
<!-- page-number-citation, NOT page-number-citation-last !!! -->
<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/>
```

> This **does not work in certain situations**: multiple page sequences, an initial page number other than 1, or
>   forcing a certain page count, thereby producing blank pages at the end.
>
> In **XSL 1.1**, you get another option to do this: **make sure an "id" is set on the page-sequence** and reference
>   it using fo:page-number-citation **-last** . First, the page-sequence:

```
<!-- page-sequence, NOT block-->
<fo:page-sequence id="seq1" ...
```

> After that, reference the last page the page-sequence generates:

```
<!-- page-number-citation-last, NOT page-number-citation !! -->
<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="seq1"/>
```

> **Warning**:
>   *There is no reliable way to get the real total page count with FO mechanisms. You can only get page numbers.*

---

So in your case, please:

1. Change `<fo:page-number-citation-last/>` to `<fo:page-number-citation/>`.
2. Or alternatively,  introduce an `id="lastPage"` attribute on your (last) `page-sequence`, not your last `block`, then you can refer to it via:

   ```
   <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page"/>`
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestions but, the error is the same, java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence. I've updated first post with "complete" xsl file that I generate from parts. Tried both suggestions but the error remains the same. Still, under v2.2 it works and above is valid for everyhitng up to 2.3 from 1.1 version. And I'm only having issues with 2.3 version of FOP.